# Destructor for a linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, destructor

I have a linked_list and currently my destructor is not working properly. Not entirely sure why.
Can somebody explain me how to solve this?

```
class linked_list {
 private:

struct node
{
    // String in this node
    std::string data;

    // Pointer to next node
    struct node *next;
};

//First item in the list
struct node *first;
```

Here is my destructor

```
linked_list::~linked_list(void)
{
while (first)
{
    delete first;
    first = first->next;
}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
delete first;
first = first->next;
```

When you delete `first`, but then try to access `first->next`. Cache `first->next` into a temp variable of type `node*`, then do `delete first` to fix this:

```
struct node* temp;
while (first != NULL)
{
    temp = first->next;
    delete first;
    first = temp;
}
```

Comment: so just flip it should do it?

Comment: @user1665569 You also need a temporary pointer to the next element, otherwise it is lost forever when you delete `first`

Answer (score 1):

change to

```
 linked_list::~linked_list(void)
{
struct node *next;
while (first != NULL)
{
    next = first->next;
    delete first;
    first = next;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you 'delete' first, you actually clear all the links from it. Now, if you try to access some other node using this, will not produce the required result.

First, you have to point that node with some other pointer, so that you still have some link which you can access later.