# List with nodes destructor

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, destructor

Before asking my question, I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265967/writing-a-linkedlist-destructor) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672812/destructor-for-a-linked-list) questions.

I have a chained List where each node points to the next node. Basically :

```
class List{
    class Node{
        Node():next_(NULL){}
        ~Node(){
            if(next_){
                delete next_; 
                next_ = NULL;
            }
        }

        Node* next_;
    }

    List():head_(NULL),tail_(NULL){}

    void add_node(){
        tail_->next_ = new Node(); 
        tail_ = tail_->next_;
    }

    Node* head_;
    Node* tail_;
}
```

I removed all the useless information but the piece of code given above is
enough to get the idea (at least I hope, I'll update it on request).

What concerns me is the destruction part. Assume I have a `List` where I have
added many node with `add_node()`. When the `List` destructor is called, it
recursively calls the destructor of each `Node` until it reaches the last node
which has `next_==NULL`. The `List` is therefore destructed from the end.

I have never had any issue with this until today where I had a list with
~180000 elements (quite a large memory usage but definitely not overwhelming
the RAM) which returns a segfault...

If I do a while loop destroying the last elements (no recursive call of the
destructor) everything works fine.

Is there a limiting number of recursive call of a destructor ? Did I miss
anything else ?

Comment: Too deep recursion. Do you need to be using this homemade and probably-not-the-right-data-structure for your program?

Comment: I guessed so... Yes, it is part of a large code that can't really be changed... I can upgrade the destructor but the overall class can't be changed.

Comment: You are going to have a to switch to an iterative destruction in the list destructor instead of using recursion in the nodes.  Recursion does not scale well as you can consume all of the stack space with all of the function calls.

Comment: It was an elegant solution... But I will change it... I just wanted to make sure that this was a possible problem. If someone tells me that this can't be problematic, I would be stuck because I don't know what else could cause my segfault... thx

Answer (score 0):

this way recursion can be avoided:

```
~Node(){
    while(next_)
    {
        Node* temp = next_->next_;
        next_->next_ = NULL;
        delete next_;
        next_ = temp;
    }
}
```